# RoR Twilio Texting App - Cannot get Twilio to send SMS. No error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, sms, twilio, twilio-api

### Update: Thanks to everyone for their suggestions. I tried everything, but nothing worked until I updated my credentials (my API, token, and phone number) to be the production credentials. And now I can receive text messages, even though the text messages confusingly say they have been sent from trial account. I'm happy the app is working, but bewildered as to why production credentials work when test credentials do not. If anyone has an idea, let me know.

I'm using RoR to create a web app that sends a text message to a phone number, using the Twilio API. Because I don't know what I'm doing, I'm following the instructions here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/adding-sms-capabilities-to-your-rails-app/
which are super great, but also written 4 years ago. I noticed that Twilio uses a different resource URI (Messages vs SMS/Messages), and I've tried to adjust the code to reflect this update, but I think I'm still missing something, because I'm not receiving any text messages. And yes, the phone number I'm using is 100% verified.
Even more perplexing, neither my console nor the Twilio SMS logs are giving me any error messages. The console output looks something like this:

(42.6ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered text template (0.0ms) 
Completed 200 OK in 710ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 42.9ms)

which looks pretty chill to me. And there's not even an entry in the log. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      render text: "Thank you! You will receive an SMS shortly with verification instructions."

      # Instantiate a Twilio client
      client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

      # Create and send an SMS message
      client.account.messages.create(
        from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
        to: @user.phone,
        body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
      )
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Specifically, I tried changing `client.account.messages.create()` from `client.account.sms.messages.create()`, to no avail. I also tried changing it to `client.account.sms.messages.sendMessage()`, but I got an error telling me the method was undefined.

Anywayyyy, can anyone give me a hint as to how to troubleshoot? This is the only piece of code I've changed, so maybe I have to alter something else?

Thanks in advance. :)

P.S. Why do the `end`s at the end of my code look so screwy? They don't look like that in Sublime.

Comment: You are right to remove the `.sms`, that is the deprecated endpoint and using `client.account.messages` is correct now. Can you specifically log the result of the created message and tell me what it says?

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you do something like:

```
#config/initializers/twilio.rb
  #move your TWILIO_CONFIG initialization here
  TwilioClient = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

#models/user.rb
class User
  after_create :send_verification_message #best done with a background worker

  def send_verification_message
    TwilioClient.account.messages.create(
        from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
        to: phone,
        body: "Thanks for signing up. To verify your account, please reply HELLO to this message."
        )
    end
  end
end
```

You can then remove the one defined in the controller. I believe with this, you should either be able to send the messages or see the errors returned

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I still am not seeing any errors - or texts. I noted your comment 'best done with a background worker'. Is this necessary? I'm not quite sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

paste it into your controller

```
def twilio_client
    Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'])
    end


    def send_otp
      twilio_client.messages.create(to: 'phone_number', from: 'twilio_phone_no', body: "temporary identification code when prompted." )
    end
```

set from field as per your twilio account and set to fild to client phone no "+4563217892"
and call controller send_otp method.

for more information check this link:

http://rubyonrailsdocs.blogspot.com/2016/05/twilio-application-step-by-step-process.html

Answer (score 1):

Kira,

Take a look at [Why aren't my test credentials working?](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/why-arent-my-test-credentials-working) regarding your update.

With the proper credentials, I'd suggest trying an updated tutorial [SMS notifications in Ruby and Rails](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/server-notifications/ruby/rails#6) where the `send_message` function looks like this:

```
def send_message(phone_number, alert_message, image_url)

  @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']

  message = @client.account.messages.create(
    :from => @twilio_number,
    :to => phone_number,
    :body => alert_message,
    # US phone numbers can make use of an image as well.
    # :media_url => image_url 
  )
  puts message.to
end
```

Take a look at the full code in the tutorial and let me know if it helps at all.

Comment: Hi Megan! Thanks for your input! It didn't work, but I did eventually get the app working. Will update my intiial question with details.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to follow up on this - I authored the question. It turns out that you can't test in this manner with Twilio's test credentials. As outlined in the Twilio documentation, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183808-Why-aren-t-my-test-credentials-working-:

Although Twilio will provide test credentials for users to exercise parts of the Twilio REST API, these cannot be used to send messages or make a phone call. This is why my app worked when I used production credentials. I wasn't charged for using these production credentials (I think you must get a couple of freebies).

For the record, the code I followed from that tutorial is correct, with the exception of the deprecated .sms endpoint mentioned in the original question. That did have to be altered.